# fmincon function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, calibration

I wrote the following formula in order to solve a minimization problem. But when I run the code, I always get the following error:

Error using barrier
Objective function is undefined at initial point. Fmincon cannot continue.

```
function out = Objectivefunction(x,r,q,K,T,S0,type,marketprice)
    %loss function to find optimal heston parameters
    %rho = x(5);
    %kappa = x(2);
    %theta = x(4);
    %eta = x(3);
    %vol0 = x(1);
    %sigma0 = sqrt(vol0);
    integration_rule = 1;
    Price = zeros(length(T),1);
    diffr = zeros(length(T),1);

    %FFTCarrMadanHeston(kappa, eta, theta, rho, sigma0, K, T, S0, r, q, type, integrationrule)
    %price using FFT
    for t = 1:length(T)
        Price(t,:) = FFTCarrMadanHeston(x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), sqrt(x(1)), K(t), T(t), S0, r(t), q, type(t), integration_rule);
        diffr(t,:) = marketprice(t) - Price(t);
        %diffr(t,:) = (abs(marketprice(t) - Price(t)))/Price(t);
    end
    out = sqrt(sum((diffr).^2)/length(marketprice));
end

% calibration
v0 = 0.0654; %
kappa0 = 0.6067;
eta0 = 0.0707;
theta0 = 0.2928;
rho0 = -0.7571;

x0 = [v0,kappa0,eta0,theta0,rho0];
x0;

% computation of the interest rate for each maturity
r = spline(interest_rate(:,1), interest_rate(:,2), T);
T = T/360; % maturity in years

%calibration parameters
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
e = 1e-5;
lb = [e e e e -.999]; % Lower bound on the estimates
ub = [100 10 10 10 .999]; % Upper bound on the estimates
optimpar = fmincon(@(x)Objectivefunction(x,r,q,K,T,S0,type,marketprice), x0, A,b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
```

I do get an outcome when I calculate the value of the objective function in the intitial point. However, once I do it in the fmincon function , it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Where the function body  ends? Could you edit your post to separate the objective function from the rest of the code please?

Comment: The objective funtion ends at % calibration

Comment: With your permission, I'll edit the code so is valid, unambiguous MATLAB code.

Comment: Few things that seem off so far: **(1)** `q`, `K`, `S0`, `type`,`marketprice` are not defined; **(2)** the calculation of `r` is using `T` before `T` being defined **(3)** `T` is defined in terms of itself, **(4)** `FFTCarrMadanHeston` is an unknown function. In order to make sense of this, can you briefly clear these points?

Comment: `
clear all;

%READ DATA
%-------------------------------
option = xlsread('OptionData300322.xlsx', 'Summary');
stock = xlsread('OptionData300322.xlsx', 'Stock price');
interest_rate = xlsread('OptionData300322.xlsx', 'rates');

S0 = stock; %stock price at initiation
disp(S0)
q = 0.012; %dividen yield UNH
T = option(:,2);
K = option(:,1);
type = option(:,4); %Put or Call dummy
market_price = option(:,3);



`

Comment: The carrmadanheston is defined as follows: 

FFTCarrMadanHeston(kappa, eta, theta, rho, sigma0, K, T, S0, r, q, type, integration_rule)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, i'm not familiar with stack overflow :)

Comment: Also sorry --- the edits I provided are still pending, because my reputation is not high enough. About the `FFTCarrMadanHeston`: is it providing complex values? because if yes, then the output of your `Objectivefunction` could be also complex --- and `fmincon` minimizes only real functions.

Comment: function out = HestonCharacteristic(r, q, kappa, eta, theta, rho, sigma0, S0, u, t)

d = ((rho*theta*u*1i-kappa).^2-theta^2*(-1i*u-u.^2)).^0.5;
g = (kappa-rho*theta*u*1i-d)./(kappa-rho*theta*u*1i+d);

p1 = 1i.*u.*(log(S0)+(r-q).*t);
p2 =  eta.*kappa .*theta^(-2).*((kappa-rho*theta*u*1i-d).*t - ...
    2*log((1-g.*exp(-d*t))./(1-g)));
p3 = sigma0^2*theta^(-2).*(kappa-rho*theta*u*1i - d).*...
    (1- exp(-d*t))./(1-g.*exp(-d*t));

out = exp(p1).*exp(p2).*exp(p3);
end

Comment: Indeed, the FFTCarrMadanHeston function uses the HestonCharacteristic function